# C hex character array to string representation

Tags: c, hex

If I have the following C array:

```
 char arr[4];
 arr[0] = 0x11;
 arr[1] = 0xc0;
 arr[2] = 0x0c;
 arr[3] = 0x00;
```

How can the above data be converted into a string as shown below ?

```
 char* str = "11c00c00";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    char arr[4];
    arr[0] = 0x11;
    arr[1] = 0xc0;
    arr[2] = 0x0c;
    arr[3] = 0x00;

    size_t len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);

    char* str = (char*)malloc(len * 2 + 1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        const static char table[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f' };

        unsigned char c = (unsigned char)(arr[i]);
        unsigned int lowbyte = c & 0x0f;
        unsigned int highbyte = (c >> 4) & 0x0f;

        str[2 * i] = table[highbyte];
        str[2 * i + 1] = table[lowbyte];
    }

    str[2 * len] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n",str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code. Can you please explain why you did `c & 0x0f` and `(c >> 4) & 0x0f` ? Thanks.

Comment: `c & 0x0F` is "calculate the lower 4 bits of the byte value represented by c".  That yields a value between 0-15.  Similarly, `(c >> 4) & 0x0f` is "calculate the upper 4 bits of c".  Google for "c bitmask tutorial" and "c bitshift tutorial". Lots of good sites to explain this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Convert each character to an unsigned character (so the 0xc0 isn't negative), then convert it to an integer and output as a two digit hexadecimal value.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define INT(x) ((int)(unsigned char)(x))

int main()
{
     char arr[4];
     arr[0] = 0x11;
     arr[1] = 0xc0;
     arr[2] = 0x0c;
     arr[3] = 0x00;

     char *str;

     str=malloc(32);
     sprintf(str, "%02x%02x%02x%02x",
         INT(arr[0]), INT(arr[1]), INT(arr[2]), INT(arr[3]));

     puts(str);
}
```

Output is:

> 11c00c00